# start editing encountered one or more layers with error and can not continue this data is not editable

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, topology

I create two feature classes by importing an already existing layers then I create a topology and I set the rule such that a point feature class must be covered by endpoints of the other line feature class and there was one error. When I tried to edit I received the error: start editing encountered one or more layers with error and can not continue this data is not editable.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please export these layers into another database and then restart arcgis desktop and catalog, then check it.